# How to find the corresponding Id for parameter passed into a new page for saving via Sharepoint api

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api, parameter

Overnight, with the help of this forum, I figured out how to save a parameter passed via a query string to my Sharepoint api call for "**Name**" field.   I'd like to take this one step further, and instead of saving "**Name**", I want to save the "**Id**" that corresponds to the "**Name**".   I know that "**Name**" is a Lookup field in my list.

The line of code I'm struggling with is this:

```
var siteIdFromParameter =   getSiteParam('Site', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl)?$Id="/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')"
```

Here's all my code:

```
        function getSiteVars() {
             var vars = {};
                var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                vars[key] = value;
                });
            return vars;
        }

        function getSiteParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
            var siteparameter = defaultvalue;
            if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
            siteparameter = getSiteVars()[parameter];
        }
            return getSiteParam;
    }


    function addFeatureSuggestion() {

        var siteNameFromParameter = getSiteParam('Site', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
        var siteIdFromParameter =   getSiteParam('Site', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl)?$Id="/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')"

        var item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.AddListItem" },
            "SiteId": siteIdFromParameter,
            "Title": $('#inputTitle').val()
        };
```

Comment: Your code doesn't quite match up with your description.  Do you want the ID of the Site specified by the SiteUrl querystring param?  Or do you want a second querystring param called "Name" that will be used to find the ID of an item in a List?

Comment: Hi @willman    I'm passing in one parameter (SiteUrl) and want to find the Id that corresponds with SiteUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Id of the Site, you will need to make a separate web service call to `/_api/Web` before you save your new Item.  If you are using `.ajax` to make your service calls, make sure to do your next step inside the `.then` or `.done` method since it is an asynchronous call.  Note, this presumes that SiteUrl is a valid SharePoint site that the current user has at least read access to.

```
function getSiteVars() {
     var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
        });
    return vars;
}

function getSiteParam(parameter, defaultvalue){
    var siteparameter = defaultvalue;
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
    siteparameter = getSiteVars()[parameter];
}
    return getSiteParam;
}


function addFeatureSuggestion() {
    var siteUrlFromParameter = getSiteParam('Site', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrlFromParameter + "/_api/Web",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
    }).then(function (data) {
        var siteIdFromParameter = data.d.results[0].Id;

        var item = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.AddListItem" },
            "SiteId": siteIdFromParameter,
            "Title": $('#inputTitle').val()
        };

        // do the rest of your item saving in here
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @willman.  I'll be trying this out later tonight.  The .then is new to me.  Reading up on that now.  Will report back later.

Comment: Well, I' haven't got it to work yet  :-(  When I use debugger in Chrome, it seems to "skip" right over this line of code  var siteIdFromParameter = data.d.Id;

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the `then` function.  It is an asynchronous call, and the `then` is the callback.  If you are stepping through the code synchronously, you won't get to an asynchronous callback.

Comment: If you typically have used the `.ajax` method by passing in a success and error handler functions, you can certainly use that technique here too, just move the code that I put in the `then` method into your success handler.

Comment: with a minor change, I'm back in business.  I learned a TON.  Thank you for your help!   Thank you @willman!!!!!!!!! 

```siteIdFromParameter = data.d.results[0].Id```

Comment: oops, sorry for the syntax error, I have updated the answer with your discovery.